# How to set base url in angular 6 app (getting 404 page after refreshing)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have followed the below procedure.

1. ng build --base-href=/myapp/
2. Deployed into the tomcat server
3. Accessing: http://localhost:8080/myapp/ (open home page)

After refreshing the home page, it is giving a 404 error page.

Comment: So, it loads the home page at URL /myapp/ the first time, and when you refresh (and the URL is still /myapp/), it doesn't load it anymore? Or has the URL changed when you refresh?

Comment: Have you set up a routing module? If so, can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using HashLocationStrategy. Put `useHash: true` while defining your routes:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy